# Where is an external file opened from Firefox kept after I save it?

Tags: firefox, file-location

I opened a photoshop document from firefox (i.e. clicked open rather than save). I did a lot of work on it then saved and closed photoshop CS6. No error was given. Where is that file now? I know if I had saved it instead of just clicking "open" before working on it, then it would be in the downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the Temporary Items folder. To open it, type `%TEMP%` in the address bar of an Explorer window, then press Enter (if you're on Windows). From there, it might be obvious, or you could try a search in the folder. The files in the Temp folder are automatically deleted, so it might not be there anymore.

[image]